# How can I bind system events to VBA class event handlers

Tags: winapi, events, excel, excel-2003, vba

I've been trying for the last couple of days to get around the lack of inheritance in VBA when using `WithEvents` MSForms objects in a VBA class module can allow for assigning multiple event handlers to a series of controls across a UserForm. I'm mainly after the `_Enter` and `_Exit` events, and these are in `MSForms.Control` rather than the (subordinate) `MSForms.TextBox` that my controls are. Consequently, adding each TextBox to the tbTextBox variable in a class module along the lines of:

```
Private WithEvents tbTextBox as MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub tbTextBox_Exit()
 ' Do Something Here - doesn't work
End Sub

Private Sub tbTextBox_DblClick()
 ' Do Something Here - works
End Sub
```

doesn't work for Exit (in MSForms.Control), although DblClick works fine (in MSForms.TextBox).

I'm more or less at the point where, since I know these events do get raised (just at the parent level), I'd like to hook into the controls in my form via the Win32 API, and manually watch for any of these events occurring, then raise an event of my own to re-implement the functionality on my own.

So far I'm drawing a blank from Google, but I thought some more advanced VBA coders than I might be able to point me in the right direction. Should also note, I'm working with Excel 2003, so VB.Net isn't an option, and the environment is highly sandboxed, so no external modules or .dlls can be used.

Comment: You've maybe already read this in your research, and it may not apply, but I recommend Tushar's advice at the end of this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/isvvba/thread/04ab7d68-e3fe-4c1e-83d9-61c0521dda7c

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about consistent user experience than data validation... I want to ensure whichever control has focus it has different formatting from those around it to highlight where a users is in the form. For expediency I've actually had to hard-code a number of them for now, but really hoping to go back and do it right if I can!